# api call from one docker container to other in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to make API call from one container to another. I make network bridge so that api do not travel whole web instead directed to local container.

```
version: '3'

services: 
    auth_services:
        container_name: auth_services
        env_file:
            - auth_service.env
        restart: always
        networks:
            - n_bridge

        image: auth-service
        ports: 
            - '3000:3000'
    normal_service:
        container_name: normal_service
        networks:
            - n_bridge
        env_file:
            - normal_service.env
        environment:
            - AUTH_SERVICE_URL=auth_services/api/v1 # this point to AUTH service 
        restart: always
        image: normal-service
        ports:
            - '3001:3000'
        links:
            - auth_services
networks:
    n_bridge:
```

I made api in normal_service to call auth_service

```
async function pingAuthService(req, res){
    const url = process.env.AUTH_SERVICE_URL + '/';
    console.log("pingAuthService Called")
    console.log("AUTH_SERVICE ",process.env.AUTH_SERVICE_URL)
      let response;
    try{
        response = await axios({
            method:'GET',
            url,
        })
        if(!response.data.error){
            res.json({ 
                title: 'Express',
                message: response.data
            });
        }else{
            res.json({ 
                title: 'Express',
                message: 'Error From Auth service'+JSON.stringify(response.data) 
            });
        }
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ 
            title: 'Express',
            message: 'Error From Auth service' 
        });
    }
}
```

It is giving me error.

```
> normal_service    | pingAuthService Called normal_service    |
> AUTH_SERVICE  auth_services/api/v1 normal_service    | { Error:
> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 normal_service    |     at
> TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
> normal_service    |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', normal_service    |  
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED', normal_service    |   syscall: 'connect',
> normal_service    |   address: '127.0.0.1', normal_service    |  
> port: 80, normal_service    |   config:  normal_service    |    { url:
> 'auth_services/api/v1/', normal_service    |      method: 'get',
```

I also tried giving port in docker compose file like

```
    environment:
        - AUTH_SERVICE_URL=auth_services:3000/api/v1
```

But the error is same as above

Comment: Can you try with this url : `http://auth_services:3000/api/v1` ?

Comment: More specifically you need to include `http://` at the front of `AUTH_SERVICE_URL` so it's interpreted as an absolute URL and not a relative URL.  (You don't need the manual `networks:` configuration, `links:`, or to manually specify `container_name:`; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details.)

Comment: @leopal it is giving 404

Comment: @RajanLagah   At first you should debug connectivity between the containers with a simple `ping` command. If that fails then something is wrong with your compose setup. If succeeds then the issue lies in your code. The url that I have provided should work, according to the info you have provided.

Comment: @leopal GOT IT was doing something wrong and adding `http` help me.